# How do I get the latest message from my MySQL Schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, join

I'm assuming this is very easy but I'm having issues figuring it out. I want to get the most recent message for each conversation for each user with my query in the most efficient way possible.. My schema for the 2 tables looks like this..

```
CONVERSATIONS --
id
fromUserId
toUserId
timestamp

MESSAGES --
id
conversationId
userId
message
timestamp
```

Here's what I've come up with so far, but this only gives me the first message - which is not right. I need the newest message (Highest UNIX timestamp)

```
SELECT c.fromUserId, c.toUserId, c.productId, m.userId, m.message, m.timestamp
FROM conversations c, messages m
WHERE (c.fromUserId = '9' OR c.toUserId = '9')
AND m.conversationId = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried a few other ways, like subqueries and what not but that doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Also to note, conversationId is unique in the messages table.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 <.....> GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC`

Comment: Ooops, in MySQL you will just add `LIMIT 1` to the end, ignore the `TOP 1` in my previous comment.

Comment: Since you use `GROUP BY c.id` I assume you want the most recent message per conversation, not just the single most recent message among all conversations. If you want the former, this is a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] question. Follow that tag and see many other answers to that type of query.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can limit your query to 1 result like so:

```
SELECT c.fromUserId, c.toUserId, c.productId, m.userId, m.message, m.timestamp
FROM conversations c, messages m
WHERE (c.fromUserId = '9' OR c.toUserId = '9')
AND m.conversationId = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```